# How can I verify if a column is only decimal using Power Query M formula?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am new to Power Query. I need to replace the value of column4 by only decimal values in column5 and column6 based on a search criterion for column3 and provided that those columns contain only decimal values. The sample of the data file is as follows:

[image]

I tried to use `Number.Mod` , `Value.Type` and `Value.Is` functions but that did not work. Here is the code for my latest attempt:

```
    = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",each [Column4],
  each if Text.Contains([Column3],"Instant Payment BSF/MBK") then 
          if Number.Mod([Column5], 1) = 0 then [Column5] 
          else if Number.Mod([Column6], 1) = 0 then [Column6]
          else [Column4]              
  else [Column4],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column4"})
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

I managed to to resolve it by using the following code:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",each [Column4],
  each if Text.Contains([Column3],"Instant Payment") then 
          if Value.Is([Column4], type number) or Value.Is(Value.FromText([Column4]), type number) then [Column4]
          else if Value.Is([Column5], type number) or Value.Is(Value.FromText([Column5]), type number) then [Column5]
          else if Value.Is([Column6], type number) or Value.Is(Value.FromText([Column6]), type number) then [Column6]
          else [Column4]              
  else [Column4],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column4"})
```